# Facebook Like button default text

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a FB Like button on my site, but when it gets clicked, the resulting "summary of this link" text on your FB feed is erroneous.

I generated the like button when there was nothing on the site's present URL (I had just registered it). Now, when I click "Like", the text description that shows up in my Facebook feed is this:

`"Learn about HAIKU.LI from this free business profile provided by Network Solutions"`

That text shows up underneath the title of my page (which is displaying correctly as `"Find Haiku in Your Tweets"`).

How do I clear the default description text? I've tried regenerating the button to no avail. That Network Solutions text is certainly not present on my site. Is there some kind of `og` tag for description?

## Edit

The url for the page is:

[www.haiku.li](http://www.haiku.li)

The html for the button:

`.fb-like{"data-font" => "arial", "data-href" => "http://www.haiku.li", "data-layout" => "button_count", "data-send" => "false", "data-show-faces" => "false", "data-width" => "100"}`

The meta tags in the `head` section:

`%meta{:content => "Find Haiku In Your Tweets!", :property => "og:title"}/
        %meta{:content => "website", :property => "og:type"}/
        %meta{:content => "http://www.haiku.li", :property => "og:url"}/
        %meta{:content => "http://www.haiku.li/assets/logo.png", :property => "og:image"}/
        %meta{:content => "Haiku.li", :property => "og:site_name"}/
        %meta{:content => "[my FB id]", :property => "fb:admins"}/`

Everything seems to work as it should except that it adds in the extra description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text (and image, title, etc) that are used in the facebook stories are extracted from the page itself.

Facebook scraps the url and use the returned data in order to get the info it needs to create the story.
You can control that data of course by using the [Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) and defining the og tags.
You can use the [Debugger (AKA Linter)](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check what data is returned from your site and how facebook "sees" it.

In the [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) documentation is says this (which is important and people sometimes miss it):

> **When does Facebook scrape my page?**
>
> Facebook needs to scrape your page to know how to display it around
>   the site.
>
> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are
>   up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph
>   page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the
>   Facebook URL Linter. Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs - it
>   will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference.
>   However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your
>   page every 24 hours.
>
> The user agent of the scraper is: "facebookexternalhit/1.1
>   (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

---

## Edit

Ok, I think I know what's the problem.
Looking at your code you neither have the [description meta tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element#The_description_attribute) nor the *og:description* tag, because of that facebook is probably taking "default description provided by my domain registrar".
You should add both tags.

It's a guess.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked my site with the Debugger and fixed an error (hadn't specified all the tags). However, even though the debugger shows no more errors, the offending text is still there. I've also verified (with the debugger) that the default text isn't present on my site. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code for the fb like button, also can you post the url of the page in question?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, but when I try it I get "Find Haiku In Your Tweets!". Go to the Like Button tutorial (linked in my answer) and put your url in the "URL to Like" and you'll see that it works well, at least it did for me. Maybe you have a cached version, try to clear your cache.

Comment: I also get the correct title. However, the actual entry it makes in my facebook timeline also includes the erroneous default description provided by my domain registrar (it displays this beneath the correct title, the correct link, and correct image).

Comment: Yep, I was missing the :description tag. Thanks for your help!